# Mapnik OGCServer doesn't work if theres no active internet connection

Tags: mapnik, ogcserver

Didn't find anything similar so: I have a mapnik OGCServer on an ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (vmware player) which works fine. The problem occurs  when i disconnect all network connections, when ogc server kind of hangs. On some occasion there was a fault saying something about a broken pipe. I actually noticed this on the airport where i had no connections. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: on VM that will break it - VM uses https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1#Bridged - Bridged Networking is used when you want your vm to be a full network citizen, i.e. to be an equal to your host machine on the network.

Comment: @Mapperz You are really helping me out on those little things that would otherwise cost me days of time to figure out :D thanks a ton